# Como usar a tag <address>, dúvidas?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

É correto usar o elemento `<address>` apenas para um e-mail?

Por exemplo:

`<address><a href="mailto:exemplo@gmail.com">exemplo@gmail.com</a></address>`

Exemplos que sempre vejo são algo como endereço da rua, cidade, etc..

Teria alguma regra dizendo onde eu posso ou não adicionar esse elemento `<address>`, ou posso colocá-lo onde bem entender? obg :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não está errado colocar apenas um e-mail, pois esse elemento serve para inserir informações de contato sobre sua página quando usado de forma global dentro do elemento `<body>` ou sobre um autor em casos onde ele está sendo usado dentro do elemento `<article>`.

Ele pode ser usado para informar desde um simples e-mail de contato como no seu caso, como também para informar um endereço completo de um local físico. Segue alguns exemplos abaixo.

Exemplo simples:

```
<footer>
  <address>
    <p><a href="http://www.w3.org/Consortium/contact-mit">MIT</a></p>
  </address>
</footer>
```

Exemplo com endereço:

```
<footer>
  <address>
    <h5>Contate-nos</h5>
    <p> 
    Rua Leonardo Mathias, 100, Sala 30<br>
    Vila Roitman - Santos/SP, 11244-444 </p>
    <p>
      <abbr title="Phone">Tel:</abbr> (11) 5555-4577 
     </p>
  </address>
</footer>
```

Exemplo com artigo:

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>The Very First Rule of Life</h1>
    <p><time pubdate datetime="2009-10-09T14:28-08:00"></time></p>    
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam autem similique totam molestias dolorum, eius iusto cupiditate ex debitis fuga. Quaerat minima harum esse iste voluptates quod, magnam placeat sapiente.</p>
  <footer>
    <address>
  Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>.<br>
  Visit us at:<br>
  Example.com<br>
  Box 564, Disneyland<br>
  USA
    </address> 
  </footer>
</article>
```

Normalmente esse elemento é usando dentro do elemento `<footer>`, mas você pode usá-lo em outros elementos também, desde que esteja sendo usado para informações de contato, assim não estará errado.

Comment: Entendi, obg pela resposta ;)